# What does this mean root@DESKTOP-9R2GIKO?

Tags: command-line

What does this mean `root@DESKTOP-9R2GIKO`? I donk think this direct to my Disk.

When is use the `ls` command, the following is printed.

```
bin   dev  home  lib    media  opt   root  sbin  srv  tmp  var
boot  etc  init  lib64  mnt    proc  run   snap  sys  usr
```

I'm using Ubuntu Terminal in Windows 10 and I'm new.

Answer (score 7):

```
root@DESKTOP-9R2GIKO
```

- `root` is the user name you are working with
- `DESKTOP-9R2GIKO` is the host name

The output you are getting from `ls` is the content of `/` (root) in your file system hierarchy.

To make sure where you are you can run: `pwd`, it should return: `/`

To find out what each directory in `ls` output is contain and responsible of run:

```
man hier
```

For example it states that:

> /  This is the root directory.  This is where the whole tree starts.

---

To make sure about the meaning of `root@DESKTOP-9R2GIKO` you can run: `echo $PS1`, you should get an output containing/similar to:

```
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]
```

Pay attention to `\u@\h`, `\u` is username, `@` is a literal and `\h` is your host name.

If you run `cat /etc/hostname` you should also get: `DESKTOP-9R2GIKO`.

Answer (score 2):

By default, when you start a new shell (Terminal) in Ubuntu, the following will show up.

```
<name of user>@<name of host machine>
```

In your case, it's `root@DESKTOP-9R2GIKO`. So that means you are logged in as the `root` user to a machine named `DESKTOP-9R2GIKO`.

As for `ls`, it's a command which lists a directory's content.

If you are interested in learning more about the command line, I would strongly suggest taking some courses. You can find lots of free courses online. You can also find a [brief description](https://askubuntu.com/tags/command-line/info) about in the tag's description here on Ask Ubuntu.